# Output after macro expand seems not as per understanding (may be wrong understanding)

Tags: c, macros

Hi need to under stand execution steps for below program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SQUARE(x) (x)*(x)
void main()
{
 int i = 5;
 printf("%d\n", SQUARE(++i));
}
```

As i have understanding like macro expanded like `(++i)*(++i)` and as result `(7)*(6)` = 42 but the output is `49` which i don't understand why?

Comment: 'need to under stand execution steps for below program' why?  If it's too difficult to easily understand, (which it is), it's not fit for purpose.  Get rid of the pre-increment and add an increment as a separate line above the macro 'call'.

Answer (score 1):

That's precisely the problem with macros, if you don't pay attention, you end up with undefined behaviour. See [Why are these constructs (using ++) undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior)

`(++i)*(++i)` is undefined behaviour, the result can be anything including exploding your computer.